# SVG: animateMotion with animated path

Tags: animation, svg

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wangjiaji/cHaNg/) there are 2 animated paths, *curve0*:

```
<path id="curve0" stroke="black" fill="inherit" stroke-width="3" 
    fill-opacity=".5"
    d="M 0,100 
        C  50,100  50,50, 100,50 C 150,50 150,100 200,100
        C 300,100 200,50, 300,50 C 400,50 300,100 400,100">
    <animate attributeName="d"  dur="5s" 
        values="M 0,100 
        C  50,100  50,50, 100,50 C 150,50 150,150 200,150
        C 250,150 250,50, 300,50 C 350,50 350,100 400,100;

        M 0,100 
        C  50,100  50,150, 100,150 C 150,150 150, 50 200, 50
        C 250, 50 250,150, 300,150 C 350,150 350,100 400,100;

        M 0,100 
        C  50,100  50,50, 100,50 C 150,50 150,150 200,150
        C 250,150 250,50, 300,50 C 350,50 350,100 400,100" 
    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path>
```

and *curve1*,

```
<path id="curve1" stroke="black" fill="yellowgreen" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity=".5" >
    <animate attributeName="d"  dur="3s" 
        values="M 100,0  0,100   70,50   130,150  200,100  z;
                M 100,0  0,100   70,150  130, 50  200,100  z;
                M 100,0  0,100   70,50   130,150  200,100  z" 
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path>
```

as you can see the ellipse moves along well with *curve0*, but if you change curve0 on line #36 and #46 to *curve1*, the ellipse stops moving.

Why *curve1* doesn't work and where in the specification states *animateMotion* works with one kind of animated path and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you need to change the <mpath> element to point to curve1 too, not just the <use> element (which draws the curve).

```
<animateMotion dur="5s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
  <mpath xlink:href="#curve1"/>
</animateMotion>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHaNg/2/).

Comment: I tried the fiddle in the latest version of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, only in Firefox did it work.

Comment: FWIW it worked fine in Opera 12 (Presto) too. Looks like a bug in webkit/chrome then.